# Third party DLL not found C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, dll

So I have this code:

```
[DllImport("ECDM400Drv", EntryPoint = "ECDM400_Open", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern bool Open(byte PortNo);
```

And a dll file called ECDM400Drv.dll, which I placed in the root folder, src folder, and even the windows system32 and syswow64 folders just to be safe. I did this because I have another third party dll that I am using, which I had set up the same way and it worked, but when I do the set up with this dll, I get a dll not found exception, telling me it can't locate this file. I tried adding it as a project reference but that did not work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It could be permissions related.  The following article has some good solutions that might help you: [DllImport generates System.DllNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818482/dllimport-generates-system-dllnotfoundexception)

Comment: my permissions are set to allow all users on my machine to have "full control" on the dll files, so that shouldn't be the problem.